# Cause and solution for - pain on right side of nose after blowing nose

Tags: nose, cause-and-effect, nose-blowing

I haven't found anything online related to this "condition" and at the moment it is driving me crazy.

I have the flu, it is nothing serious except, many an occasion I have blown my nose and a "bubble of air" is trapped in my I assume is my sinus canals. It usually takes a few hours to eventually come out, and the sound associated is like spraying a can of aerosol or the like, which comes from my right-side of my nose, where the pressure is/was.

Why does this occur and how can I prevent this, when it has occurred, what remedy should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like as you say air is being forced under pressure into one of the paranasal sinuses and being trapped by a one way valve similar to [pneumosinus dilatans](http://radiopaedia.org/articles/pneumosinus-dilatans). But in your case the valve breaks down and lets the air release.  Perhaps you shouldn't blow so hard, or try blowing one nostril at a time so that the pressure isn't so great.